# Light works half the time

Tags: lighting

its strange cause the light in my bathroom ceiling  works only half the time. No flickering. does NOT seem to be after long use (so NOT from thermal overload). Any ideas???

Comment: Is it fair to assume you have tried different bulbs?

Comment: Incandescent bulb?  Fluorescent?

Comment: On this site need new panel. Where it is loose wire nut ask mike.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my mom's place. I would turn on the lamp, and sometimes it would work and others not, even after trying several bulbs.

I figured out that the light screw was too old, and was not so conductive anymore. The replacement screw (see pic below) costed less than 1EUR. It took me 5min and a screwdriver to replace it, and it's working great now.

[image]

Comment: @robert moody - based on the photo, I think he meant the light socket, not just a loose wire